# In CSS Position, is Absolute inside Relative, Absolute to the document or the parent element?

Tags: css

Why doesn't position:absolute always mean absolute to the document?  When you have a divB, for example, inside a another divA.  If divA had no position, would divB's absolute be absolute to the document?

If you create a position element and you put another element inside of it that has position, is that child *always* relative (for lack of a better word) to the parent/containing element?  In other words, if I have a container that is position:relative, but a child that is position:absolute, that absolute is only absolute to the parent, right?  Thanks.

Comment: yes. that absolute is only absolute to the parent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element with position: absolute is absolute to it's nearest **non-static** parent container. For example, I have a position: relative div, inside that a normal paragraph, and inside that an absolute span. That span is absolute, not to the paragraph (which has no defined position, so is default to static) but to the div which is relative.

For relativeness to the whole document, you used position: fixed. The reason (in your example) that divB would *seem* absolute to the document, is because it doesn't find any parents with position:relative, and eventually ends up using the body.

Comment: I didn't know you could position inline elements. :).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute is not necessarily absolute relative to its parent, rather its nearest ancestor that is positioned.  So if the parent of an absolutely positioned element doesn't have a declared position, then dependency will fall until the ancestor (parent of parent of parent... etc) is positioned.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
(Note the Property Values section toward the bottom)